# Output filter for dates

Tags: 7, datetime, wysiwyg

How can I change the output of dates in a long text field based on the locale?

I was looking for a module that might work with WYSIWYG to denote a date within a text field.

My goal was to allow articles to be viewed in several locales that use different date formats, without having to create separate versions of the articles.  All of the article content is the same except for references to dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Drupal [date module](https://drupal.org/project/date).

Users can set their timezone and date will automatically be converted to the timezone of current user (you are presented with options about this when creating the field).